# How to loop through output of a command?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, loops

I have a command in a bash script which gives the following output

```
repository: docker/images
tags:
- 0.1-1
- 0.1-2
- 0.1-3
- 0.1-6
- 0.1-7
- 0.1-9
```

However, from the above output, I only need to browse through `0.1-1, 0.1-2 ...`and run a different command.

Please let me know how this can be achieved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a test to check if the line starts with `-` using `grep`:

```
... | grep '^-' | while read -r line; do echo "$line"; ## Do stuffs; done
```

As `grep`'s output is buffered, you might want line buffering, need GNU `grep`:

```
... | grep --line-buffered '^-' | while ...; do ...; done
```

Or use `stdbuf`:

```
... | stdbuf -oL grep '^-' | while ...; do ...; done
```